# Copy a row to the bottom of a table in the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I had a VBA code that copies data entered in row 3 to the last empty row in a table that is found in the same sheet. This copying is triggered once a button a clicked.
This was working fine with the code below:

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

' define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of 
your sheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Record ClientsDetails")

' determine the last row with content in column D and add one
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' copy some cells into their ranges
ws.Range("D3:F3").Copy ws.Range("D" & lRow)
ws.[D1].Select
```

I have made inserted a new row before column D to the spreadsheet, but the button is not copying anymore, even after adjusting the code. I am getting an error msg:
**Run-time error '1004'
Copy method of Range class failed**

The new code is:

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

' define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of your sheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Record ClientsDetails")

' determine the last row with content in column D and add one
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' copy some cells into their ranges
ws.Range("D3:G3").Copy ws.Range("D" & lRow)
ws.[D1].Select
```

The error is occurring on this line:
' copy some cells into their ranges
ws.Range("D3:G3").Copy ws.Range("D" & lRow)
ws.[D1].Select

The new row that I inserted has a data validation in it (i.e. now D3 has a data validation). Could this be the reason why the button is not copying Row 3 anymore? When the code was working before inserting the row, D3 did not have a data validation.

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see the edit. Thanks